# Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CategoryModel')

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to fetch data using GetX in flutter. Whenever I try to show the data I always get the following error:

```
Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CategoryModel').
```

This is my GetBuilder:

```
GetBuilder<CategoriesController>(builder: (categories) {
                    return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                      childAspectRatio: 60 / 100,
                      children: List.generate(categories.categoriesList.length,
                          (index) {
                        return _buildSingleCategory(
                            index, categories.categoriesList[index]!);
                      }),
                    );
                  }),
```

And this is my `_buildSingleCategory` widget:

```
Widget _buildSingleCategory(int position, CategoryModel category) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              new MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => new ProductListPage()));
        },
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 80,
                decoration: style.shadowContainer(),
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/kale.png'),
              ),
              Text(
                category.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
```

And this is my model:

```
class CategoryModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String photo;

  CategoryModel({required this.id, required this.name, required this.photo});

  factory CategoryModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CategoryModel(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        photo: json["photo"],
      );
}

List<CategoryModel> categoryModelFromJson(String str) {
  return List<CategoryModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => CategoryModel.fromJson(x)));
}
```

I'd be glad if someone helps me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: which line is causing the error?

Comment: return _buildSingleCategory(
                            index, categories.categoriesList[index]);
                      }),

Comment: what is the type of categories.categoriesList[index] ?

Comment: It is dynamic !

Comment: but the _buildSingleCategory required CategoryModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you're declaring `_buildSingleCategory` to accept an `int` and `CategoryModel` :

```
Widget _buildSingleCategory(int position, CategoryModel category) {
// ...
```

but here you're passing the wrong types :

```
// ...
(index) {
  return _buildSingleCategory(
        index, categories.categoriesList[index]!);
 }),
```

I assume here that the `categories.categoriesList[index]!` is a `Map<String, dynamic>`, so what you need it to modelize it to a `CategoryModel` with the `fromJson` method like this:

```
GetBuilder<CategoriesController>(builder: (categories) {
                    return GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 4,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 8,
                      childAspectRatio: 60 / 100,
                      children: List.generate(categories.categoriesList.length,
                          (index) {
                        return _buildSingleCategory(
                            index, CategoryModel.fromJson(categories.categoriesList[index]!)); // check this
                      }),
                    );
                  }),
```

Comment: It was my bad, thank you so much for that! I accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

I think categories.categoriesList is a list of Map<String, dynamic>. Make sure it is a List of CategoryModel.